# Не могу прописать клик на кнопку

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Не могу создать элемент .click() на кнопку.

Код на сайте:

```
<button class="btn__type btn__type_close">Закрыть</button>
```

Как пытаюсь сделать элемент кликабельным:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('.btn__type_close')").click()
```

Вопрос: - Как будет правильно?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn__type_close').click()
```

Comment: Уже делал так..не проходит...

Вот что пишет:

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button class="btn__type btn__type_close">...</button> is not clickable at point (574, 535). Other element would receive the click: <div class="form__group">...</div>"

Comment: @nikvand значит, очевидно, кнопка по каким-то причинам не кликабельна. А по каким — это уже вам виднее, вы нам html-код страницы и её состояние в момент клика не показали

Comment: @nikvand, кнопка перекрыта элементом `<div class="form__group">...</div>`. Добавьте в вопрос html этого куска с кнопкой